# I want to create dropdown in place of buttons for graphs change but my function is not working on <select> but with button it's working fine

Tags: html, angular, typescript, chart.js

**Here is my html and ts code, I want to create dropdown for changing graph
through chartType function but error occurs that chartType
is not a function but that function works fine with buttons but not dropdown.**

```
    <div>
        <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="chartType('bar')">Bar Chart</button>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="chartType('line')">Line Chart</button>
        <button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="chartType('radar')">Radar Chart</button>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="chartType('polarArea')">Polar Chart</button>
        
         <select name="chartType" id="chartType" onchange="chartType(this)">
            <option selected>Select Chart Type</option>
            <option value="bar">Bar</option>
            <option value="line">Line</option>
          </select>
          
    
        <div class = "chart" >
            <canvas id="canvas"> {{charts}} </canvas>
         
        </div>
    </div>
    
    

        chartType(type: any)
         {
           this.charts.destroy()
            this.charts = new Chart('canvas', {
              type: type,
              data: {
                labels: this.arr,
        
                datasets: [{
                  label: 'IR',
                  data: this.a1,
                  borderWidth: 3,
                  fill: false,
                  backgroundColor: 'red',
                  borderColor: 'red'
        
                }
                ]
              }
            })
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem should get solved, if you define a `change` event handler on your `select` element as follows.

```
<select (change)="chartType($any($event.target).value)">
```

Please take a look at this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zicr92?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchart.component.html) and see how it works.

Comment: and if I want to create dropdown for both labels of graphs i.e. IR and IY, then how to do that.